# In Sierra: How to get Qt 5.8.0 / PyQt 5.7.1 / sip 4.19 / Python3.5 to install & work correctly?

Tags: macos, python

I am experiencing trouble trying to get the combination of Qt 5.8.0 / PyQt 5.7.1 / sip 4.19 / Python3.5 to install & work correctly on my macOS 10.12.2 (Sierra).

**Steps to reproduce the problem**:

(*I am being very specific for if anyone else will ever venture here trying to accomplish the same thing*)

1. Install Python3.5 via homebrew (brew install python3.5).
2. Installing PyQt5 via homebrew however did not work as my python code complained that it could not find the pyqt module. I fixed it by applying some symlinks. Yet, the code remained buggy throwing up errors like QtGui.QApplication was missing etc. I also found multiple complains of macOS users that had run into similar problems but I could not find any real solution. So, I removed all my symlinks and ran `brew uninstall pyqt5`.
3. Then I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vityafx/e01ab56d28a2c9467cc6#file-install-script) on GitHub, and started following that so I:
4. Downloaded qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.8.0.dmg from qt-project.org
5. Downloaded SIP and PyQt5-gpl sources as mentioned in the gist.
6. I then unpacked the SIP & PyQt5 tar files. Then I executed the command:

   ```
   python3.5 ~/Downloads/sip-4.19/configure.py -d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages --arch x86_64
   ```
7. So far, so good. Also `make`, `sudo make install` & `sudo make clean`, as mentioned in the gist, executed without a problem.
8. Now, I arrived at step nr. 13 from the gist, which told me to make a small change to the `!host_build` command listed in the `~/Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri` file. The file  however did not mention any `!host_build` comment at all, so I added one myself.
9. Then, at step 15 from the gist I executed:

   ```
   python3.5 configure.py --destdir /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/bin/qmake
   ```
10. This gave a SDK path error, which I fixed by running `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` as per instruction on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524934/4041795) on Stack from people that ran into a similar problem.
11. Now, the code mentioned above in step 10 did execute, but it threw up an error:

    > Error: This version of PyQt5 and the commercial version of Qt have incompatible licenses
12. So, I searched and arrived at [a post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/56095/error-this-version-of-pyqt5-and-the-commercial-version-of-qt-have-incompatible-licenses/3) on the QT forum. It helped me solve the error by making some small adjustments to PyQt5's configure.py file (commenting out the license check).
13. Then, I was finally able to successfully run the command I mentioned at step 10 (step 15 from the gist).
14. However, when I tried to run `make` again, everything seems to be going perfect until it now throws out this error that, so far, I have not been able to fix:

    ```
    ~/Downloads/PyQt5_gpl-5.7.1/QtCore/sipQtCoreQt.cpp:1093:62: error: no member named 'WindowCancelButtonHint' in namespace 'Qt'; did you mean
          'WindowCloseButtonHint'?
        {sipName_WindowCancelButtonHint, static_cast<int>( ::Qt::WindowCancelButtonHint), 419},
                                                           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


        WindowCloseButtonHint
    ../../../Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qnamespace.h:300:9: note: 'WindowCloseButtonHint' declared here
            WindowCloseButtonHint = 0x08000000,
            ^
    ~/Downloads/PyQt5_gpl-5.7.1/QtCore/sipQtCoreQt.cpp:1106:58: error: no member named 'WindowOkButtonHint' in namespace 'Qt'
        {sipName_WindowOkButtonHint, static_cast<int>( ::Qt::WindowOkButtonHint), 419},
                                                       ~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    make[1]: *** [sipQtCoreQt.o] Error 1
    make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
    ```

Is there anyone able to help me out?

Comment: Thnx! I updated the error so it is now shown correctly. Also thnx on the other editing. Pretty new to these forums so learning as I go..

Comment: Not that it helps, but I'm in the same boat. Glad I found this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the one who did the Qt5 5.8.0 upgrade for Homebrew. This is a known problem that will persist until Riverbank upgrades their software. I suggest you contact them on their mailing list.

UPDATE: As a temporary workaround, I've added a qt@5.7 formula, and updated the PyQt5 formula to depend on it. See the following pull requests, which I've merged:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9297

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9308

Comment: Ah, well then that solves it. Well, at least, I don't have to keep searching. Thnx for the tip, I've enrolled to the mailinglist so I'll contact them there.

Comment: SB87 I've updated my answer with info about our temporary workaround in Homebrew, which should hold you over until Riverbank catches up.

Comment: Ah sorry, was away for the weekend. Still had some trouble at first, after reinstalling PyQt5 via Homebrew, but turned out it was a local mess up. After some struggling, it all works fine now. Thnx!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Also some progress upstream. PyQt5_gpl-5.8.dev1701311752.tar.gz was posted on https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5. I haven't tested it yet but presumably it will get this all working with Qt 5.8.